# rails text_field create array of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have this code :

```
<%= form_for :biblio, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
 [cut for brievity]
<%= f.text_field :auteur, size: 100, class:"champs_auteur" %>
```

That creates this html :

```
<input size="100" class="champs_auteur" name="biblio[auteur]" id="biblio_auteur" type="text">
```

I'm trying to get the name to be : `name="biblio[auteur][1]"`

I don't see how.

Comment: You can give any name that you want ..but dont forget to catch the same at the controller...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
<%= f.text_field :auteur, size: 100, class:"champs_auteur", name: "biblio[auteur][1]" %>
```